# Guidelines for building complex C++ such as QuantLib and Open Source Risk Engine in VS Code in Windows

Tags: quantlib

I am looking for a guide for build correctly complex C++ projects such as those for quantitative finance and financial engineering such as QuantLib and Open Source Risk Engine. I can configure correctly QuantLib in Visual Studio Community following standard instructions available at https://www.quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml but for personal preference I would prefer use VS Code which I like for multi language programming (Python, Rust, LaTeX etc...) and easyness of use and also plugins availability. I know that VS Code is mainly a editor, but I have installed mingw-64 as compiler, added it to the system %PATH and linked to VS Code, where I installed of course both the official C++ plugin from Microsoft and the solution explorer (.sln).
So I can compile correctly basic C++ scripts but I find issues when managing complex project like QL and ORE in VS Code
As relates QL, I tried to extend the include path in c_cpp_properties.json file with boost and QL directories... but I still get error like
"ql/qldefines.hpp: No such file or directory"

Does anyone knows any resource to use complex projects even if other than QL and ORE?

Thank you in advance for any contribution!
Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried to follow the steps in https://www.quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml?

Comment: yes, and I confirm it works with Visual Studio Community, which is a self-cointaining IDE (it has build-in compiler, environment configured with solution files etc.. VS Code is instead a "bumped" text editor, multilanguage, easy to use and endowed of a marketplace with thousands of cool plugins..) I installed a the mingw-64 and linked it to VS code, it works at building simple .ccp source files... but I think VS Code can't properly manage solution files (.sln) for complex projects as Visual Studio Community does, futhermore maybe it struggles in compiling multifiles project (I'm not sure)

Comment: It will be helpful if you share your code and entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried this? - i can get it to work on VS Code

clang++ -O2 -std=c++17 -I/Users/XXXX/YYYY/libtensorflow-cpu-darwin-x86_64-2.14.0/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/quantlib/1.31.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/include main.cpp -c

clang++ -L/Users/XXXX/YYYY/libtensorflow-cpu-darwin-x86_64-2.14.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/quantlib/1.31.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/lib -lQuantLib -ltensorflow main.o -o ExecC3d

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).